# On super-abundant numbers in certain intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$. An integer $n>1$ is said to be a super-abundant number if $\sigma(n)/n > \sigma(s)/s$ for every integer $s \in (0, n)$.

My question: For every $y> 10^{16}$, is there some super-abundant number $x \in ( y, y + \frac{9y}{\log y}]$ ?

Comment: No. According to [this page](https://oeis.org/A004394/b004394.txt), the second smallest  super abundant number $> 10^{16}$ is $12129898443062400$. Letting this be $y$, if the answer to your question was yes, one would have to find the next super-abundant number $< 15077669686807192$. But the next one is $21371725828252800$.

Comment: @Jeremy Rouse, indeed. In fact, much more is true according to Theorem 9 of http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1969__97__129_0/, which I was informed of just now.